# Async task is not triggered

Tags: android, service, android-asynctask

I have an app which should send locations once the app is stopped, 
i override onstop method and it run the service perfect 
but when it reached location sender nothing happened here is my service code:

```
    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        dbHelper = new DBHelper(this);
        warnniSharedPreference = new WarnniSharedPreference(this);
    }

    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        LocationSender locationSender = new LocationSender();
        locationSender.execute();
        return android.app.Service.START_NOT_STICKY;
    }
    private class LocationSender extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {
        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void aVoid) {
            super.onPostExecute(aVoid);
            if (null != response) {
           dbHelper.deleteAllRecords(DBHelper.LOCATION_TRACKER_TABLE_NAME);
                dbHelper.deleteAllRecords(DBHelper.IMAGES_TABLE_NAME);
            }
        }
        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... voids) {
            try {
                int start = 0;
                int end = 0;
                ArrayList<WarnniLocation> locationArrayList = dbHelper.getAllLocationRecords();
                int locationGroupSize = (int) Math.ceil((double) locationArrayList.size() / (double) 60);
                for (int i = 0; i < locationGroupSize; i++) {
                    MultipartUtility multipartUtility = new MultipartUtility(Constants.ADD_LOCATION_DATA, "UTF-8");
                    multipartUtility.addFilePart("image", new File(imagesPaths.get(i)));
                    multipartUtility.addFormField("driverId", String.valueOf(warnniSharedPreference.getKey("id")));
                    if (i == 0) {
                        end = 59;
                    } else {
                        end = i * 60 + 59;
                        if (end >= locationArrayList.size()) {
                            end = locationArrayList.size() - 1;
                        }
                    }
                    multipartUtility.addFormField("locations", new Gson().toJson(locationArrayList.subList(start, end)));
                    response = multipartUtility.finish();
                }

            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return null;
        }
    }
```

Please advise 
thanks in advance and any help will be appreciated

Comment: Why using `AsyncTask` in services? Services are already running in background.

Comment: then should i send the request direct?

Comment: I got android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException

Comment: @Yupi Services run on the UI thread

Comment: yea as i understand my , how could i get guaranteed of the async task is triggered?

Comment: Thy using this -> new LocationSender()).executeOnExecutor(AsyncTask.THREAD_POOL_EXECUTOR)

Comment: @HabooltakAna okay my bad Daniel is right services actually running on UI thread, did you try to debug your code by putting breakpoints in `AsyncTask` and see will compiler hit breakpoints?

Comment: Yes the problem i debug the code it walk over execute and nothing happened, my activity already running another service maybe this issue ?

Answer (score 0):

Hi there is no problem usind asynctask in services . All you need to do is to use doin background method only because that runs in the background . But onPostExecute method runs on ui thread. So remove onPostExecute method.

Comment: thank you for your time, well my activity already run a service i couldn't run two services at same activity ?

Comment: which service you are using intent service or normal service ?